# Синоним типа между файлами

Tags: c#

Есть проект из нескольких файлов. В файле `A` объявлен синоним типа, например так:

```
using MyMap = Dictionary<int, string>;
```

Тут же есть функция, использующая этот тип в качестве параметра или/и возвращаемого значения. Допустим такая:

```
public MyMap foo(MyMap map) { ... }
```

Т.к. функция объявлена как `public` она доступна извне, т.е. в том числе и из другого файла. Однако из-за того, что синоним типа (`using`) может быть использован только в пределах одного файла, получаются такие решения:

1. Использовать в файле `B` исходный тип, т.е. `Dictionary<int, string>`;
2. Добавить аналогичный `using` в файл `B`;
3. Отказаться от `using` и сделать полноценный класс `MyMap` (т.е. обёртка над словарём).

У каждого подхода есть свои плюсы и минусы. Хотелось бы понять, на каком правильнее остановиться и почему.

Может быть задачу вообще надо решать иначе (ваш вариант)?

Comment: Проще всего убрать синоним. Здесь у вас не особенно сложный тип, чтобы жалеть о потере синонима.

Comment: @nzeemin более говорящее имя упрощает понимание. В примере это не очень видно, но под 'MyMap' подразумевается нечто осмысленное. Поэтому имя важно.

Comment: На мой вкус, если есть что-то осмысленное, со своим именем — то оно не должно _являться_ `Dictionary<int, string>`, а _агрегировать_ его. То есть на мой вкус, класс с (приватным) полем типа `Dictionary<int, string>`.

Comment: @alexolut в таком случае имя нужно для переменной, а не для типа. Лучше создать класс тогда, как минимум Вы упростите себе жизнь при рефакторинге. К примеру, если надо вдруг переименовать тип.

Comment: Попробуй поместить `using MyMap = Dictionary<int, string>;` после `namespace XXX`

Comment: @Tsar оно и так внутри 'namespace', иначе пришлось бы использовать полностью квалифицированное имя 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'

Comment: @VladD минус в том, что придется прокидывать все те методы, что используются от Dictionary. Ну или сделать поле публичным. В принципе это позволит ввести свой тип, видимый во всех модулях без особого усложнения кода.

Comment: @alexolut: Скорее всего, смысл того, что вам надо, не совсем совпадает с `Dictionary`. Поэтому придётся пробрасывать два-три метода, а может, вы и поменяете сигнатуру и смысл немного.

Comment: Отказаться от using, сделав полноценный класс MyMap. Раз у вас имя MyMap весьма осмысленное - то делайте сразу класс. Если имя не особо осмысленное - используйте исходный тип. Но раз вы уже задумались о осмысленном имени, то оно у вас явно ещё где-то всплывёт.

Answer (score 1):

Синоним типа прежде всего нужен для сокращения полного имени класса, если не хочется подключать всё пространство имён и засорят intellisense и для разрешения конфликта имён. Иногда синоним используется для удобства программиста пишущего конкретный класс.

Чем меньше вы будете использовать наследования и композиции, тем понятнее будет ваш код. Всё нужно делать в меру. Так как вы передаёте параметром достаточно простой класс Dictionary то создавать обёртку не имеет никакого смысла. Назовите этот параметр myMap и другим будет понятно что это такое.

Наследование и в том числе композиция применяется только в случае изменения поведения исходного класса. Создавайте новые типы только в том случае, если вы программируете новое уникальное поведение. А для понимания достаточно осмысленного названия параметра.

Поэтому в файле A создайте свой синоним если вам как программисту так удобнее и понятнее и назовите этот параметр осмысленным именем. А в файле B просто передавайте Dictionary. Но если вам удобнее то добавьте декларацию using и в файл B.